# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be parsed

Tags: android, firebase-storage

```
val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(bookUrl)

   // val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(bookUrl).child("downloadsCount")
    storageReference.getBytes(Constants.MAX_BYTES_PDF)
        .addOnSuccessListener { bytes ->
            Log.d(TAG,"downloadBook : Book downloaded...")
            saveToDownloadsFolder(bytes)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            Log.d(TAG,"downloadBook : Failed to download book due to ${e.message}")
            Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to download book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

please help, ive been trying hard

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: It'd probably also help if you show the value of `bookUrl`, as that is the most likely cauase of the problem